# Properly specifying path for git pull from my local development machine

Tags: python, git

I'm trying to setup Fabric so that I can automatically deploy my Django app to my web server.

What I want to do is to pull the data from my Development machine (os X) to the server.

How do I correctly specify my path in the git url?

This is the error I'm getting:

```
$ git pull  
fatal: '/Users/Bryan/work/tempReview_app/.': unable to chdir or not a git archive  
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

This is `.git/config`:

```
[core]  
    repositoryformatversion = 0  
    filemode = true  
    bare = false  
    logallrefupdates = true  
    ignorecase = true  
[remote "origin"]  
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*  
    url = /Users/Bryan/work/my_app/.  
[branch "master"]  
    remote = origin  
    merge = refs/heads/master
```

Comment: Are you running `git pull` on the development server or your local machine?

Comment: Pulling **to** a server sounds pretty wrong. And how do you expect that URL to your dev-machine to work? Is that a mapped network drive?

Comment: Because I'm using Fabric, I can execute commands from the server. I'm going to switch to git push though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your server, create a folder called `myapp`. Chdir to this folder, and then run

```
server ~/myapp$ git init
```

Then, let git know about your server. After this, push to the server's repository from your local machine.

```
local ~/myapp$ git remote add origin user@server:~/myapp.git
local ~/myapp$ git push origin master
```

Anytime you want to push changes to your server, just run `git push`. If you make a mistake, just log in to your server and `git co last-known-good-commit` or something to that effect.

Git hooks are also very useful in situations such as the one you're facing. I would give you pointers on that but I don't know what your workflow is like, so it probably wouldn't be very helpful.